# SendKeys in c# - not able to send multiple keys

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am actually activating the button click event of the VB application through my c# code - I have created shortcut key of the button click and calling with the help of below code.

The code is working fine but button 2 click event is not firing.

1.Step - to call the Click event of button1 of VB project

```
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = @"C:\New\MyProj.exe";
  Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
  IntPtr h = process.MainWindowHandle;
  SetForegroundWindow(h);
  // Send it Alt-X
  SendKeys.SendWait("%x");
  Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

2.Step - to call one bat file

```
  Process process1 = null;
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo1.FileName = @"C:\App\Test.bat";
  process1 = Process.Start(startInfo1);
  Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

3.Step - to call the Click event of button2 of VB project

```
   //again i am setting main window as my VB project and calling another click event.
   SetForegroundWindow(h);
   SendKeys.SendWait("%h");
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

The last click event is not working, why? - Alt +h is not firing

Comment: Why is this question tagged `vba`, and all the different C# versions? Actually you are not doing a button click, but rather sending the "_"-key to the application ... Have you done, or are you able to do, any debugging on this issue yourself (like adding a listener to the application, and log all the `SendKeys`)?

Comment: Why is the subject referring to Visual Basic?

Comment: what do you mean with "multiple keys"? combined, consecutively ...? Did you do any debugging to verify your assumption (like adding a key-listener in your host and do some logging)?

Comment: I have passed Send key ( Alt + o) to cick one of the event after that i am running one bat file after that again i am trying to Send (Alt +h) keY. But that is not firing.

Comment: @Coder2014 can you verify that the application receives the keys?

Comment: Yes [Alt +o] is very much fired and i have verified the same

Comment: @Coder2014 please stop adding all the different C# versions as tags. `C#` and `SendKeys` seems legit enough ...

Comment: @Coder2014 Where/When did you test "%o"?! That is not in your question! Can you verify that the application receives "%h"? Or does that fail? Either the pointer `h` is invalid, or the application does not handle "%h" correctly - Please provide that information, as we can not test your setup remotely ...

Comment: my bad ..i have tested %x

Comment: @Coder2014 still: "Can you verify that the application receives "%h"? Or does that fail? Either the pointer h is invalid, or the application does not handle "%h" correctly - Please provide that information, as we can not test your setup remotely ...". Your test for "%x" is of no representative value!

Comment: I have created shortcut for both the buttons [button1 & button2] - button1 shortcut - x & button2 shortcut is h. First event is firing correctly, problem is i am not able to send h key

Comment: @Coder2014 again, can you verify that the problem is the sending part? what if you switch step 3 with 1? please put some effort into nailing your very specific issue - atm there are like 5 distinct possibilities which you could simply reduce to 1 ... Please also incorporate the *@*username-style in your comments, to reply to a specific person - otherwise there'll be no notification, and I am so done with constantly pulling ... sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to kill the first process by using process.kill()
and again start the VB project by

```
   startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = @"C:\New\MyProj.exe";
   Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
   process.WaitForInputIdle();
   SetForegroundWindow(h);
   SendKeys.SendWait("%h");
```

Comment: What if the program is in a certain state after "%x" which is needed for "%h"?